# Angular: Material Button follow the Header Size

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-material, angular10

How do I make a mat-icon adhere to the header size? This is not working, the arrows are still very small.

```
  <h1>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="testEvent()">
      <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </h1>
```

**SCSS:**

```
h1 {
  @include font(400,40px);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply below css this will make a mat-icon adhere to the header size.

```
.mat-icon, .mat-icon-button{
  font-size: inherit;
}
```